# Exibir e ocultar imagens com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso de uma ajuda no que diz a respeito ao código-fonte abaixo:

**CSS**:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
var total = 5;
    var numero = 1;

    function mostrar() {
        if (numero <= total) {
            var inicio = (numero - 1) * 1 + 1;
            for (var x = inicio; x < inicio + 1; x++) {
                document.getElementById('resultado').appendChild(document.getElementById(x));
            }
            numero++;
        }

    }

    var imagens = 5;

    function apagar() {

        if (imagens != 0)
            for (var i = imagens; i > imagens - 1 ; i--) {
                document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
            }
        imagens = i;
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
<center>
    <div id="resultado"> &nbsp; </div>
    <hr width="33%">
    <input type="button" value="mostrar" onclick="mostrar()" /> | <button onclick="apagar();">esconder</button>
</center>

<span id="dados" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/1.jpg" id='1'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/2.jpg" id='2'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/3.jpg" id='3'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/4.jpg" id='4'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/5.jpg" id='5'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
```

Ele funciona quase perfeitamente, o problema é que .. não volta imprimir no HTML as imagens após serem removidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que estás a complicar um bocado, não há necessidade para tantas operações (partindo do príncipio que seja isto que queres), tenta assim:

```js
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

function mostrar() {
  for (var i = 0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
    if(imgs[i].style.display == 'none' || imgs[i].style.display == '') {
      imgs[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
      break;
    }
  }
}


function apagar() {
  for (var i = imgs.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(imgs[i].style.display == 'inline-block') {
      imgs[i].style.display = 'none';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="mostrar" onclick="mostrar()" /> | <button onclick="apagar();">esconder</button>

<span id="dados">
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/1.jpg" id='1'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/2.jpg" id='2'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/3.jpg" id='3'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/4.jpg" id='4'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/5.jpg" id='5'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
```

Para mostrar percorremos todas as imagens até encontrar uma que esteja com display none, ou que não tenha qualquer display inline definido, esta passa a ter display `inline-block`.

Para esconder fazemos o mesmo, mas comçamos a percorrer as imagens da ultima para a primeira, até encontrarmos uma que tenha o display `inline-block` (que é display com que ficam quando as mostramos), esta passa a ter display `none`.